# What does Yoda's species eat?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

I am phrasing the question like this because of possible spoilers for current or upcoming *Star Wars* material. Yes, I'm being deliberately vague about even what series or movie I'm protecting.

> Yes, I realize that in Chapter 2 of *The Mandalorian*, we observe the child eating a frog.
> However, for some reason, I always imagined Yoda was a vegetarian...
> So, besides what we observe in this episode of *The Mandalorian*,

What evidence exists in which levels of canon about the dietary habits of Yoda, Yaddle, or possibly other members of their species?

Comment: Assuming Yoda is vegetarian, perhaps that has more to do with his connection to the Force than to his species?

Comment: I guess the question is wrong. I think you meant to ask: “**Yoda’s species eat, what does?**” 

Comment: Have you seen the size of droid-eating fish and frogs on dagobah? You would be vegetarian, too, if you were alone in a swamp with these.

Comment: Ate a frog, the child did. Cannibalism, this is. Strong with the dark side, it must be.

Comment: Comments about spoilers and tags deleted. Please take that discussion to the [meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12805/should-a-topic-tag-be-avoided-because-it-might-be-a-spoiler).

Comment: Maybe it was a plant-frog?

Comment: Even if Yoda was strictly vegan, it doesn't actually tell us much about the species' natural diet.  Case in point: humans can be vegan, but are naturally omnivorous.

Comment: @Shreedhar Yoda tends to use object-verb-subject ordering (from a quick Google, only used IRL by the Warao people, so I don't have a good reference to hand), so I think that translating your question from Yodish to English that actually means "What eats Yoda's species?" or "What is it that preys on Yoda's species?". Confusingly, I *think*, though I'm not certain, the Yodish sentence "What eats Yoda's species?" translates to the English sentence "What is it that Yoda's species eats?".

Comment: *What eats, Yoda's species does?*  Or  *Eats what, Yoda's species does?*  Would be the correct and acceptable phrasings.

Comment: In episode 7 Greef Karga says the Child is carnivorous but that's because he observed the Child eating meat. Since Yoda eats root leaf stew they are probably omnivorous or their dietary regime changes with age.  Clouded this species eating habits are.

Answer (score 45):

Paleontologists deduce the eating habits of extinct animals by analyzing the shape (morphology) of their [teeth](https://digfieldschool.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Lesson-7-Teeth-Final.pdf). Consider how we use our own teeth: The front teeth (incisors) are knifelike and used to tear large pieces of food (such as an apple) into manageable chunks, and the fangs (canines) act like stabbing knives. The back teeth (molars) are relatively flat and used to crush chunks of food into a digestible mass. Mammalian predators tend to have more prominent incisors and canines than we do, and their molars tend to have sharp ridges that allow the opposing teeth to act like a pair of scissors rather than a mortar and pestle; they bolt their food without grinding it. Herbivores tend to have more prominent molars that allow extensive grinding to release nutrients from tough leaves and other plant matter. Humans are omnivores with a relatively versatile set of teeth.

We can apply these concepts to Yoda's species, but the results are somewhat inconsistent, as shown in this [selection of photos](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsBattlefront/comments/bctm24/y_o_d_a_t_e_e_t_h/).

[image]

His teeth look very human, if well worn, in most scenes, with visible incisors and canines in the middle photo; we can't see whether molars exist but the shape of the jaw suggests that there are additional teeth. Yoda could be an omnivore based on these photos. In the left scene his visible teeth look triangular and sharp, clearly the mouth of a predator, but this scene doesn't seem to be from the main series of films. As Valorum points out, Yoda has also been seen making a vegetable stew, so he eats plants at least. Conclusion: Yoda's species is omnivorous but Yoda himself may practice vegetarianism.

Comment: The hidden assumption is that the character designers for Yoda knew about how paleontologists deduce eating habits, and that they cared.

Comment: That kind of thing is true of a lot of these answers, isn't it? But it doesn't take much specialized knowledge to give a predator sharp teeth. I'm just using the tools I have. An artist might have cited a website on how to draw [teeth](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/358036239099573720/) and used a somewhat different approach. The knowledge is out there to be used.

Comment: @jgn A hidden assumption of your comment is that something is only true of a character if the relevant authors intended it to be true. This is not the case. A simple example: suppose the writers simply never stopped to think about whether the Millennium Falcon contains a bathroom. Nonetheless from the fact that the Falcon is designed for long-range transport operated by humanoids, we can deduce that it does contain a bathroom, even if the writers never had any intentions one way or another about the issue.

Comment: the middle left image with very sharp teeth is from The Clone Wars, which is just as canon as the films. In other words...you can't deduce anything from his teeth shape, since there is no consistency. You especially can't deduce anything if you are then trying to use real-world science

Comment: @NKCampbell Thanks for the clarification. In that case, canon is going to have a tough time explaining why Yoda's teeth changed so radically through his lifetime! Hmm... Carnivorous youth followed by omnivorous old age? or do the teeth wear down to rounded nubs after the eight hundredth year? -- As to jgn's comment, why should discussions of science fiction exclude science?

Comment: it's just a design aesthetic - nobody really thinks Vader's helment changed shape dramatically between the events of RotS, Rebels, and ANH. Different media begets different representations. Re: science - it's just how things are often done around here :) - what reason is there to think that our science applies to the Star Wars universe? Lightsabers, people breathing in space without helmets or other protection, hyperspace, etc....slippery slope that

Comment: The problem with this is we have living animals such as the Panda where teeth analysis would lead to the wrong conclusions.

Comment: @Ceph I would _assume_ the author intended for math to work the same everywhere.  I have no reason to assume elsewise, but I also would not say it’s “true” without author intent.  I would just call it a very reasonable assumption based on context.  If someone wanted a canon answer showing that the math did work the same, it would actually likely be difficult to prove as true without something from the author.  Reader/viewer interpretations aren’t necessarily true, even if they are completely consistent with what you see.

Answer (score 24):

While on Dagobah, Master Yoda ate fruit and seeds. It's not clear if he's a vegetarian

> Soon, the lowlands would all be marshy swamp again, and he would plant last season’s seeds. Then, before the sun began its long journey away, they would sprout. The gray clouds would come back and hold in the planet’s humid air, and the sprouts would grow and flower and yield their fruit before a quarter orbit had passed. And by then the sun would be far enough away that the rains would plunge down again, and the floods begin their inundation, and Yoda would trudge back to the uplands, carting behind him the food for the long season.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: From a Certain Point of View - There is Another](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/From_a_Certain_Point_of_View)</sup></sub>

He also chews his [gimer stick](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gimer_stick), a gift from the Wookiees, but largely for its medicinal properties, and we see him and Luke eating "root leaf stew" which apparently [contains various roots, leaves and swamp weed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/132688/20774) although the 'Human' version of that stew [contains meat](http://web.archive.org/web/20110821032529/http://www.starwars.com/kids/do/crafts/f20081126.html).

Answer (score 6):

### Canon: Yoda is omnivorous

In Canon, Yoda is omnivorous. In the comic "[The Trial of Dagobah](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Trial_of_Dagobah)", from the 2019 [*Age of Rebellion* comic special](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Age_of_Rebellion_Special_1), Yoda is in exile on Dagobah, and finds he has plenty of edible plants, but no meat:

[image: Panels from "The Trial of Dagobah" showing Yoda in bed and in his kitchen in his hut.]

> Narration: ...sleeps. But **fitfully**. This night, like so many others before it, **haunted**. By the **dream**. Of anger. Of hate. Of **suffering**. He stirs awake... ...to a reminder that his larder is bare. Plants, yes—**always** plants—but no **meat**.

He sets out to hunt with a bow and arrow:

[image: Comic panels from "The Trial of Dagobah" showing a herd of beasts and Yoda assembling a bow and arrow.]

> Narration: They run in herds, these creatures. The best source of **meat** the old master's been able to find here. He carries no lightsaber. He would never diminish the weapon of the Jedi in pursuit of filling his own belly. In any case, he resolved long ago he would never wield another lightsaber.

### Legends: Yoda is even more omnivorous

From [*Yoda: Dark Rendezvous*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Yoda:_Dark_Rendezvous):

> Frankly, even beings who would follow Yoda to the gates of Death preferred not to share his meals. Perhaps traveling the length and breadth of the galaxy had given the Master a more wide-ranging palate than mere mortals, or perhaps he was so evolved a being that he didn't care what he put into his body; or perhaps when one lived eight-hundred-odd years all one's taste buds died. Whatever the reason, the old gnome's preferred foods were notoriously disgusting. He was fond of hot, swampy stews that smelled like boiled mud; small dirt-colored appetizers that jiggled uneasily on the plate; and viscous drinks, both hot and cold, that ran the gamut from burned syrup to grainy sludge. As Master Leem settled on the bench beside him, the oldest and greatest of the Jedi was peering happily into a bowl of dark brown-and-gray stew, studded with little floating chunks of what looked like raw animal fat and spackled with the scales of some small reptile. The whole concoction smelled like dead womprat that had been left out in the sun.
>
> "Fought well this morning, your Padawan did," Yoda mumbled around a mouthful of stew.
>
> <sub>(Source: *Yoda: Dark Rendezvous*, Chapter 4, page 83 of first edition)</sub>

Comment: An excellent, and fully canon find.